# Django is installed but python3 does not find it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm having problems running Django. I installed it with pip3 and then it says:

> The script django-admin is installed in
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin' which is not
>   on PATH.

So I tried to modify my PATH in the bash.profile like this:

> export DJANGO=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin

This did not help so as I ran in terminal:

> django-admin.py startproject firstdjango

it just says:

> -bash: django-admin.py: command not found

I don't know what to do to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: you should try django-admin startproject firstdjango  without .py extenstion

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin django-admin startproject firstdjango`. if the command succeeds, persist `PATH` changes: open `~/.bash_profile` and add two lines: `PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin` and `export PATH`.

Comment: Why aren't you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Tried that aswell, see the comments in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a Directory somewhere, lets name it "Django"
2. cd to "Django" directory
3. create virtualenv --> virtualenv django
4. source django/bin/activate
5. install django --> pip3 install django
6. cd to created 'django' directory
7. django-admin startproject first_project
8. Enjoy!

Comment: I tried also that, and it says in the pip3 installation part that: Collecting django
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django

Comment: and if you do 
   ' pip install django '(so without the 3)

Comment: other question, are you trying to install/download this from behind a corporate network, you could be having certificate issues....

what does this output: pip install -vvv django

Comment: pip install django provided the same result, could not find a version. With -vvv got a lot of errors. I'm not behind corporate network. This is one error:
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645)

Comment: On Unix the default configuration file is: $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf which respects the XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variable.

On macOS the configuration file is $HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf.

On Windows the configuration file is %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini.



then add this to config file:

[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org